# Change section height

Tags: html, css, sass

i have set the height of all sections to `min-height: 600px`.
but there are some sections that i want the height to change.
i tried to just do `height:300px` and even `height:300px!important` but nothing changes.

css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "non-serif";
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1f2a 1.2%, #191d28 1%) 1px 0, #fff;
  background-size: 240px 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}


section {
  min-height: 600px;
}


section#info {
  height: 300px !important;


}
```

what am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to overwrite the `min-height` of this section...

```
section#info {
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```